# Set Theory Introduction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

what does it mean that a set is element of itself if a set is element of itself I must add it one element and then that set is not the old one so contradiction

Comment: What are you having issues with? What do you understand of the proof (that there does not exist any set $x$ such that $x\in x$) and what do you not?

Comment: It is difficult to think of a set which might reasonably be regarded as a member of itself, but this does not means that this "idea" implies a contradiction...

Comment: Oh, @MauroALLEGRANZA, **now** I understand the question. The second part, (the one after the non-existing punctuation) was supposed to be an attempt of proof. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1):

It means that $\{x\}\subseteq x$. If you add a new element you end up with a new set, let's say $x'$, it is in deed a different set but it satisfies $\{x\}\subseteq x\subseteq x'$. In Zermelo Fraenkel set theory this cannot be the case because of an axiom that, intuitively states that "a set cannot be an element of itself"; it is called foundation or regularity. However, if we assume that Zermelo Frankel is consistent -we don't really know if it is, but we can assume it-, then when we 'forget' foundation axiom we can state:
\begin{equation}
\text{there is a set } x \text{ such that } x=\{x\}
\end{equation}
You can construct a model satisfying the above with a surjective function.